# Is there any way to put subquery in the column list of a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a SQL query that has a column list that generates from another SQL query. I am working on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

This is the SQL query that gets a columns list

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

It returns the following

```
|          | COLUMN_NAME    |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | name1          |
| 2        | name2          |
| 3        | name3          |
```

The is the SQL query that I currently have and it works well

```
SELECT DISTINCT name1, name2 
FROM [table_catalog].[table_schema].[table_name]
```

This is what it returns

```
|          | name1          |name2          |
| -------- | -------------- |-------------- |
| 1        | value1         |a1             |
| 2        | value2         |a2             |
| 3        | value3         |a3             |
| 3        | value4         |a1             |
```

What I would like to do is get a table that contains all the columns from the first table only, like this

```
|          | name1          |name2          |name3          |
| -------- | -------------- |-------------- |-------------- |
| 1        | value1         |a1             |b1             |
| 2        | value2         |a2             |b2             |
| 3        | value3         |a3             |b1             |
| 3        | value4         |a1             |b2             |
```

This is my attempt so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name') 
FROM 
    [table_catalog].[table_schema].[table_name]
```

It does not work as expected, I also tried to use CLE and some other ways to do it. However, none of them works. It seems like not many people did this kind of query after I did some research online, I wonder is there another way to do it? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Although your question is not clear, it seems that you are looking for dynamic sql

Comment: I reckon I may need to write a for loop to generate the column list?

Comment: What is the logic for the last column `name3` ? How do you associate `name1` , `name2` to those value ?

Comment: *"I reckon I may need to write a for loop"* very unlikely. SQL is a set based language, and if you're writing a loop, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi Squirrel. 
It is a typo.
I have fixed them.
Those are random values for each column.

Comment: Perhaps I miss something here, but if it's supposed to be all columns why not use * ? If however you want to restrict the columns to select, dynamic SQL is probably the answer.

Comment: Hi ub_coding, I can't use * as I don't need all columns.  Ture, dynamic SQL is something that I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use dynamic sql for this.
here is a small step by step example. The complete code will be at the end.

First we need to retrieve the column names in a variable. We want this variable filled with all columns from `table_name` and seperated by a comma. That is why we use `for XML path('')`  The `stuff` is for dumping the first comma.

```
declare @ColNames varchar(max)

select @ColNames = stuff(( select ', ' + column_name
                           from   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                           where  table_name = 'table_name'
                           for XML path('')
                          ), 1, 2, '')
```

The content of the variable @ColNames will look like this

```
name1, name2, name3
```

with this we can build our sql statement, also in a variable

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select ' + @ColNames + ' from table_name'
```

and finally we execute it

```
exec(@sql)
```

That should give you the results you need.

And off course, you could also put the table name `table_name` into a variable, making it all a bit more flexible.
Here is the complete code:

```
declare @TableName varchar(100) = 'SomeTableName'

declare @ColNames varchar(max)
select @ColNames = stuff(( select ', ' + column_name
                           from   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                           where  table_name = @TableName
                           for XML path('')
                          ), 1, 2, '')

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select ' + @ColNames + ' from ' + @TableName

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. If this answers solves your problem then please consider an upvote and/or accept this as answer. Now about the 1, 2 in the stuff command. The select for XML will produce a result like the following: `, name1, name2, name3` and the stuff 1, 2, '' means that I want from position 1 replace 2 characters by a '' so the result is now `name1, name2, name3`

Comment: Hi GuidoG, Thank you so much for your answer. This is exactly what I am looking for. However, what I run the code, it doesn't run as expected. It doesn't show the table that I am looking for. Therefore, I checked your code and I tried to print(@ColNames) but nothing printed out. I wonder is there anything that I need to edit except the @TableName?

Comment: it works for me, did you copy/paste the code exact the same ? And yes you only need to edit the TableName variable

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have upvoted your answer. Thanks for your explanation too. That's really helpful.

Comment: I just tried it in MSSM and it works, I get the result returned with no problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239695/discussion-between-david-and-guidog).

Comment: I am at work now, I cannot open a chat, sorry